# matlab union cell arrays

Tags: matlab, union, cell-array

I need some help with union two cell arrays.

I have:

```
data{1} =   'alon'    'shmiel'
values{2} =   'Image'    'Area'
```

I want to merge them into a union, so that `data{1}` first and `values{2}` second:

```
'alon'   'shmiel'   'Image'    'Area'
```

I tried:

1. `values{2} = {data{1}(1:2),'Image', 'Area'};`
   but I got: `{1x2 cell}    'Image'    'Area'`
2. `union(data{1},values{2})`
   but I got: `'Area'    'Image'    'alon'    'shmiel'`
3. `union(data{1},values{2},'stable')`
   but I got an error: `Warning: Third argument is ignored for cell arrays.`

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really want a [union](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/union.html) (i.e. only unique values)? Or do you just want to concatenate the arrays, as suggested by your first attempt?

If you just want to concatenate, try

```
horzcat(data{1},values{2})
```